# What are the qualities of a good block cipher? Beginner, Intermediate, Advanced, Expert

Tags: block-cipher

**Notice:** I'm doing this to learn.  I know not to use a homemade cipher for anything that requires security.  I also have heard before I'm not *supposed* to be trying this, but I learn best through trying to make things from scratch, even if I fail.

Ciphers are incredibly complex, to the point most people probably don't appreciate them, myself included.  Trying to make one from scratch might help with this, so I'm looking for a list of qualities/achievables that can be worked towards for years to come.

This is the list so far, for a good block cipher at different learning levels:

Beginner :

1. Encrypted output can not be broken by hand.  The level of encryption during WW1 or so.

Intermediate :

1. Changing a single bit in the input should have a 50% average chance of changing each bit of output.
2. Each byte should have a 1/256 chance of not changing (basically #1 ^ 8)
3. The number of bytes found in similar by search should be very few (I need to write down the math, but my estimate is around 5%)

Advanced:

1. Not sure yet?

Expert :

1. Immune to [Differential cryptanalysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_cryptanalysis)?

---

This list is very incomplete, but gives an example of what I'm looking for.

**What is your list of achievable qualities for block cipher at different skill levels?**

Comment: "I learn best through trying to make things from scratch, even if I fail"; in my experience, you learn best by *breaking* your homemade ciphers; putting a cipher together teaches you not much at all; coming up with clever strategies to break stuff teaches you far more than putting them together...

Comment: @poncho I agree.  I intend to do both, but am focusing on what's in grasp right now.

Comment: Asking vague open-ended questions here probably won't get you very far. If you're interested in learning about crypto, there are some excellent courses available online. [Try this one for example/](https://www.coursera.org/learn/crypto)

Comment: I'd suggest to take a course (e.g. Cryptography on the Coursera site) or join a crypto challenge (e.g. the matasano crypto challenge). With this approach you'll be trying to learn step by step and breaking things. During that you will build the ciphers / hashes more or less the way you've described. For me - it was great to understand how things work and  how much I still don't understand

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I don't think we can really separate things into skill levels as such, but there plenty of targets to aim for in terms of security goals. You'll want resistance to:

- [Differential cryptanalysis](http://www.theamazingking.com/crypto-diff.php)

  - [Truncated differential cryptanalysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_differential_cryptanalysis)
  - [Integral cryptanalysis](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F3-540-45661-9_9)
  - [Impossible differential cryptanalysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impossible_differential_cryptanalysis)
  - [Higher order differential cryptnalysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_differential_cryptanalysis)
  - [Boomerang attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boomerang_attack)
- [Linear cryptanalysis](http://www.theamazingking.com/crypto-linear.php)

  - [Differential-Linear attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential-linear_attacks)
- [Rotational cryptanalysis](http://www.skein-hash.info/sites/default/files/axr.pdf)
- [Slide attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slide_attack)
- [Meet in the middle attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meet-in-the-middle_attack)

  - [Biclique_attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biclique_attack)
- [Brute force search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brute-force_attack)
- [Side Channel attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side-channel_attack)

  - [Timing attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timing_attack)
- [Algebraic attacks](https://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387887562)
- [Partitioning cryptanalysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partitioning_cryptanalysis)
- Attacks that don't exist yet (at least, publicly)

Some resistance can be achieved via:

- Large enough keysize

  - Mandatory for simple brute force search
- Large enough blocksize

  - [A large enough size can preclude the conditions for a slide attack to be applicable](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/34078/29554)
- Avoiding using secret information in ways that leak timing information

  - [No lookup tables](https://cr.yp.to/antiforgery/cachetiming-20050414.pdf)
  - [No shuffling of arrays according to secret information](http://www.di.ens.fr/~fouque/pub/acns11.pdf)
  - No secret dependent rotations
- [High levels of diffusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_and_diffusion) that cause [the avalanche effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avalanche_effect) quickly

Some other desirable traits:

- Software efficiency on a wide variety of platforms (i.e. 8 bit, 32 bit, 64 bit)
- Key agility

  - [Ideally the key schedule is invertible](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/33975/what-are-the-requirements-of-a-key-schedule)
  - [Ideally the actual keys used each round are extracted from the invertible key schedule in a weakly one way manner (first preimage resistant)](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/33975/what-are-the-requirements-of-a-key-schedule)

Don't forget to obey [Kerckhoffs Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerckhoffs%27_principle)

After you've done all that, you might like to make your construction [tweakable](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/6185/what-is-a-tweakable-block-cipher)

Some of the mathematical concepts related to cipher design are:

- [Information theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_theory)

  - [Information Entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_entropy)
- [Finite Fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field)
- [MDS matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MDS_matrix)

  - [Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_(mathematics))
  - [Coding theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coding_theory)
- [Boolean functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_function)

  - [S-box](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_box) (meaning NxM mapping, not a lookup table)
  - [Bent functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bent_function)

Comment: I am not a fan of "key agility"

Comment: @RichieFrame May I ask for your reasons why? I can't seem to think of why that would be bad offhand.

Comment: Instead of Timing attack, I would recommend Hardware Implementation attack -> Side Channel, Fault attack. Timing falls within Side Channel.

Comment: I want to say, this is an amazing answer and I still come back to it.

Comment: @EllaRose Key agility is just sort of pointless in modern constructions. It's like a related key attack in that it's irrelevant in most proper implementations. It's better to generate a new keystream by changing a nonce than it is to rekey the cipher, so having a (relatively) slow key schedule is not a gamer changer.