# Components of Cryptanalysis

Tags: encryption, cryptanalysis, terminology

What are different components of Cryptanalysis. I can't seem to find them. Are they the same as Cryptosystem or is there any difference.

Comment: @Biv Cryptosystem has following components https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cryptography/cryptosystems.htm. So what are the components or sub-components of cryptanalysis.

Comment: [possibly related/useful answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/38148/29554)

Answer (score 3):

**Disclaimer:** this answer is opinion based.

---

#### TL;DR: The question does not really make sense. Because you cannot put things into boxes like that.

The best way to make you understand it is to make an analogy. **Cryptosystem is to Chess what Cryptanalysis is to Chess Games Strategy/Reviewing**.

As you define a Cryptosystem with the following components:

- Plaintext
- Encryption Algorithm
- Ciphertext
- Decryption Algorithm
- Encryption Key
- Decryption Key

You can define Chess with:

- a 8x8 board
- 16 white pieces (King, Queen, 2 Rooks, 2 Bishops, 2 Knights, 8 pawns)
- 16 black pieces *idem*.
- a set of rules

And you can see the review and strategy as:

- Openings moves and tactics (Alekhine's Defence, Caro-Kann Defence, King's Gambit...),
- Midgames moves and tactics,
- Endgames  and tactics,
- Mat in 3 (and more),
- pinning,
- forks,
- discovered attacks
- *etc.*

Cryptanalysis will be the *art* to look at a cryptosystem, find it's weaknesses and how to improve it:

- differential/linear/integral Cryptanalysis,
- boomerang attacks, related key attacks, impossible differentials,
- birthday bounds,
- Meat-in-the-middle attack,
- Game-based proofs,
- Shor's/Simon's/Grover's algorithm
- *etc*

Comment: I'm sorry, but what does "TL;DR:" mean? I keep seeing it in answers...

Comment: @PaulUszak "Too Long; Don't Read". synonymous to "summary" or "abstract" (in papers).

Comment: @SEJPM Geez.  Thanks - I thought it was a formatting error with my browser. Even at 23, you're not too old to learn eh?

Comment: One might argue that "how to improve it" is not really part of cryptanalysis, but rather the next step. Anyway, I agree that this question does not make at lot of sense. At most one could try to set out a few steps that one might typically go through, or list several attacker models that are possible (although those would be other questions).

Answer (score -3):

A cryptanalysis is somewhat reverse process of cryptography like in cryptography we try to hide the information and in the cryptanalysis, we test weakness of a cryptosystem.
so components of cryptanalysis can be said

**Passive cryptanalysis**: where only observation is done of the cryptosystem to find the weakness.

**Active cryptanalysis**: where a mathematical approach is used to overcome (or to reduce) the difficulty to solve the crypto problem.

Comment: But they are two main attack types; however, if you could please cite a reference to me to what you have stated.

Comment: yes, it sounds similar to security attacks because cryptanalysis is "figuring out attack that will work"

Comment: I don't think you can derive cryptanalysis into components.