# What kind of assumptions usually go into the design of block ciphers?

Tags: block-cipher, provable-security, hardness-assumptions

What are some standard assumptions made in showing the security of a block cipher?
For example, is it commonly assumed that $P\not=NP$?  To this end, are there any block ciphers whose security does not rest on the assumption that $P\not=NP$, and if so what are the assumptions?
Furthermore, do there exist any block ciphers that are provably secure under some set of assumptions?

Comment: The first question about standard assumptions is too broad. But, see [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/39792/54184) and [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/38148/54184) for some information.